# Add content to a masterpage placeholder in a specific site template

Tags: master-page, site-template, delegate-control

I have a master page which is a customized copy of v4.master. I want to add some content to a the placeholder called PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4:

```
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent 
    UIVersion="4" 
    runat="server" 
    id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottomV4">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <ul class="s4-specialNavLinkList">
      <li>
        <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
          runat="server"
          NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/recyclebin.aspx"
          ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
          ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
          ImageWidth=16
          ImageHeight=16
          OffsetX=0
          OffsetY=428
          id="idNavLinkRecycleBin"
          Text="<%$Resources:wss,StsDefault_RecycleBin%>"
          CssClass="s4-rcycl"
          PermissionsString="DeleteListItems" />
        </li>
```

I can a **<li>** element to this placeholder directly in the masterpage and it works fine. But actually I am wondering how to do add this additional content only in one specific site template, one of my configurations in **onet.xml**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [delegate control in the master page](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/create-own-delegate-control/). Then add content in a module to the site template in a feature.

I accept my solution. If someone finds a better solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sitecollection feature who will provision your masterpage. You can use a **module** for this purpose.
2. Add a feature reference in your onet.xml

Comment: Thank you. I am sure this solution will work.

Do I need an additional master page for this? I want to keep it as simple as possible. All my subwebs inherit the master page from the rootweb.